# Group queryset by related field values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have following models structure:

```py
class Chapter:
    name = ...


class Atom:
    name = ...
    chapter = FK(Chapter)


class Question:
    title = ...
    atom = FK(Atom)
```

I want to get all `Questions` related to `Chapter`, grouped by `Atom`s in this chapter.

How to do it with many queries I know:

```py
atoms = Question.objects.filter(atom__chapter__id=1).values_list("atom", flat=True).distinct()
result = {}
for atom in atoms:
    result["atom"] = Question.objects.filter(atom__id=atom)
```

I suppose that it could be done with one query using `annotate`, `Subquery` and other `Django`'s staff. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch this in one query, but you need to do the grappig yourself:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

questions = Question.objects.filter(
    atom__chapter_id=1
).order_by('atom')

result = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in groupby(questions, attrgetter('atom_id'))
}
```

Here `result` is a dictionary that maps the primary keys of `atom_id`s on a list of `Question` objects with that `atom_id`.

Comment: You typed arguments in wrong order, but thanks a lot.


`result = {k: list(vs) for k, vs in groupby(questions, attrgetter('atom_id'))}`